# How to load html views in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My Current Working code for resolving html views is like this

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/html/" /> 
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>
```

But i need to return view such as

```
return "/static/html/index";
```

**How can i make it like this?**

```
return "index";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the prefix to **`/static/html/`**

```
     <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/static/html/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>
```

So when you will return as `"index"` it will change to `/static/html/index.html`.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate the efforts. This solved my problem. Saved my day..

Answer (score 3):

if you are using spring Boot, it will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:

```
/META-INF/resources/
/resources/
/static/
/public/
```

in case of consuming , restful web service it might be a good approach if you put the resources in to the public folder,and this is how your controller should look like.

```
@Controller
class Controller{   

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
         return "index.html";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Priyamal. i didn't knew about this.