# spring boot /WEB-INF doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class App {
    @RequestMapping("/aaa")
    String home(HttpServletRequest request) {
          return "nihao";
    }
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/res/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

This code works fine. The path of 'nihao.html' is in '/static/res/nihao.html'.  But when I change the prefix to "/WEB-INF/", and create /WEB-INF/nihao.html file, I've got a 404 no message available error. and I've got the same error when I change the prefix to to /static/WEB-INF/" and create requisite file in that directory. I need someone to help me figure out. All the path is relative to the context path.

Comment: If it is directly under `WEB-INF` then you should not to setPrefix

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570109/how-to-load-html-views-in-spring/39571270#39571270 this post might help you reffer to both answers in the linked post

Comment: Are you using jar type or war type packaging? Where did you place WEB-INF directory?

Comment: @ sivaprasadreddy.k I use jar packaging, and place WEB-INF directory in webApp folder. But spring boot reference said I shouldn't use webApp folder in jar packaging. However, how can I protect static resource in jar packaging? Because WEB-INF can protect static resource.